# Mutation observer on iframe is not fired when used as target in a form for php output

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, mutation-observers

Mutation observer on iframe is not fired when used as target in a form for php output.

When change is made from within the java script with

```
targetNode.innerHTML = 'xxx';
```

the observer fires.

When the output of a php file is displayed by the form in the iframe,
nothing happens.

**What am I doing wrong ?**

Here is thet HTML/JavaScript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mutation Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="dummy.php" target='iframe'>
            <input type='submit'>
        </form>
        <iframe name='iframe'></iframe>
        <script >
            targetNode = document.querySelector('IFRAME').contentDocument.body;
            config = {childList: true, subtree: true, attributes: true};
            callback = function (mutationsList, observer) {
                alert('mutation');
            };
            observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
            observer.observe(targetNode, config);

            //targetNode.innerHTML = 'xxx'; //<= this will trigger a mutaion !!!!!!!!!!!!!

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the php file used as the action for the form

```
<?php
echo "dummy.php";
```

Comment: You are submitting a form, this will cause the iframe to do a page navigation. You will have a whole new document with a new `body` element. The observer will not be detecting changes to the new `body`

Comment: document.querySelector('IFRAME').onload = () => {
            // action
        };

Foudn out this works for me :-)